# Pandas groupby key then filter based on group and return keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the panda way of doing the following?

```
data.groupby('id').duration.max().index[data.groupby('id').duration.max() > 365]
```

I wan't to group by id and then filter using the groups and return the id where the condition was true.

using the group.filter function returns the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your code - it is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `Series` from aggregation function `max` and `index`:

```
s = data.groupby('id').duration.max()
idx = s.index[s > 365]
#alternative
#idx = s[s > 365].index
```

You can also check filtered values of `Series`:

```
print(s[s > 365])
```

But if want filter original `DataFrame` by `max` values per groups add [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`:

```
data[data.groupby('id').duration.transform('max') > 365]
```

Comment: Thank you, so no functional programming in pandas make me sad panda :(